# Select rows from biggest group with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select rows belonging to the biggest group?

Suppose we have following table, there are two Categories / Groups: `Fruits` (the bigger one) and `Vegetables`:

```
Name     | Category
--------------------
Banana   | Fruits
Orange   | Fruits
Beetroot | Vegetables
```

How to write SQL that would select only the rows from the biggest group?

```
Banana
Orange
```

Comment: For which DBMS do you want an answer?

Comment: For postgres database.

Comment: Okay, use the second part of my answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer for Oracle:

```
select *
from mytable
where category = (select stats_mode(category) from mytable);
```

This gets you one category only. So in case of a tie, you get one of the categories with maximum count arbitrarily.

And here is an answer for DBMS not supporting `STATS_MODE` but featuring standard SQL window functions:

```
select name, category
from
(
  select name, category, rank() over (order by cnt desc) as rnk
  from
  (
    select name, category, count(*) over (partition by category) as cnt
    from mytable
  ) counted
) ranked
where rnk = 1;
```

With `RANK` you get all categories with a maximum count. If you only want one of them in case of a tie, add `category` to the `ORDER BY`. (Thanks to dnoeth for the correction.)

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `RANK` will not work, but adding `category` to the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @dnoeth: Thanks for the correction. You are right of course.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (for PostgreSQL):

```
with mytable_count as (
  select category, count(category) as category_count
  from mytable
  group by category
  order by category_count desc
  limit 1
)
select mytable.*
from mytable, mytable_count
where mytable.category = mytable_count.category
```

Comment: If there's a tie (two different categories, with same maximum count), this query will only return one category's items.

Comment: Hey, you've been ignoring my answer ;-) Of course there are other ways to solve this, e.g. get all category counts; get the maximum count of these; get all categories with this maximum count; get the records for these categories. Using window functions however is more elegant and usually faster, as you access the table only once.